# what are the assertions that are used for check the order in below body in api tesing using cypress

Tags: api, cypress, e2e-testing

This is the body for reorder. How can I do assertions to check the order for particular in `array[3]`

```
{
                      "dimName": "Women's Clothing",
                      "dimOrder": 2,
                      "dimType": "wa",
                      "dimId": "category#womens-clothing",
                      "dimParent": "category"
                    },
                    {
                      "dimName": "Jewelry 1",
                      "dimOrder": 1,
                      "dimType": "wa",
                      "dimId": "category#jewelry",
                      "dimParent": "category"
                    },
                    {
                      "dimName": "Handbags",
                      "dimOrder": 3,
                      "dimType": "wa",
                      "dimId": "category#handbags",
                      "dimParent": "category"
                    }
```

Comment: Please explain a bit in detail what exactly are you looking to assert?

Answer (score 0):

If you received the above as a json response in an API test, a couple of quick examples:

Check the order of id's like this

```js
cy.request(...)
  .then(response => {
    expect(response[0].dimId).to.eq('category#womens-clothing')
    expect(response[1].dimId).to.eq('category#jewelry')
    expect(response[2].dimId).to.eq('category#handbags')
  })
```

Check the `dimOrder` field is sequential like this

```js
cy.request(...)
  .then(response => {
    const dimOrder = response.map(item => item.dimOrder)
    expect(dimOrder).to.deep.eq([1,2,3])        // deep because is array matching
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

For easier assertions on a response, especially nested properties, you can use [`cy-spok`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cy-spok). It's also quicker to comprehend.

```js
const spok = require('cy-spok')

cy.request(...)
  .its('response.body')
  .should(spok({
     propertieWithArray: [
       {
         // you can assert the properties equal exact values
         dimName: "Women's Clothing", 
         dimOrder: 2,
         dimType: "wa",
         dimId: "category#womens-clothing",                      
         dimParent: "category" 
       },
       {
         // you can assert properties meet specifications
         dimName: spok.string, // Jewelry 1
         dimOrder: spok.number, // 1
         dimType: spok.type('string'), // wa
         dimId: spok.startsWith('category'), // category#jewelry
         dimParent: spok.endsWith('category') // category
       },
       {
         // use combination
         dimName: spok.string,
         dimOrder: spok.gt(0),
         dimType: "wa",
         dimId: spok.test(/#/),
         dimParent: "category"
       }
```