# Get property response body from JSON response in Cypress

Tags: json, request, cypress

Can someone, help in solve asserting following response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "actor": {
            "account": {
                "nrql": {
                    "results": [
                        {
                            "TotalCoreUI": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried with following code:

```
 expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
            expect(response.body, 'response body').to.deep.equal(
                {"data":{"actor":{"account":{"nrql":{"results":[{"TotalCoreUI":0}]}}}},
            })
```

I want ta assert,TotalCoreUI but I receive this:
response body: expected [ { payload: { data: [Object] } } ] to deeply equal { Object (data) }

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use cy.spok to easily check nested properties in a response. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74646217/17917809

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying there is a `payload` key between `body` and `data` properties.

Try this:

```js
it('checks the response body', () => {

  const response = {
    body: {
      payload: {                 // this level is missing in your sample
        data: {
          actor: {
            account: {
              nrql: {
                results: [
                  {
                    TotalCoreUI: 0,
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }

  expect(response.body, 'response body').to.deep.equal({
    payload: { data: { actor: { account: { nrql: { results: [{ TotalCoreUI: 0 }] } } }}},
  })
})
```

or maybe the square bracket is part of the response.body as well, if so

```js
expect(response.body, 'response body').to.deep.equal(
  [
    {
      payload: { data: { actor: { account: { nrql: { results: [{ TotalCoreUI: 0 }] } } }},
    }
  ]
)
```

Comment: It's working now, it's missign the payload key, another thing do you know in this part how compare to.deep.equals only the TotalCoreUI value in that case: 0?